# Why JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION is undefiined in php 5.6.40?

Tags: php, json, docker

I have a container with nginx 1.8.1, php 5.6.40. I am using a package that uses the php predefined constant JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION (that was added according to the php doc since php 5.6.6).

But my app is throwing an exception saying : "Your version of PHP / json-ext does not support the constant 'JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION'"

I tried a :

```
php -i | grep json
```

It showed that my json version is 1.3.6

On another server it works well but the json version is 1.2.1.

Any idea why ? Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. php 5.6.40 and 1.3.6 for JSON. I use debian/jessie64. When I run: `echo JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION;` I see only errors. Most likely it's problem with system...

Comment: In my case I solved it the hard way cause I am not expert : I rebuilt a container from php:5.6.40-fpm instead of nginx:1.8.1. It was a good idea anyway because I decided to use one container for nginx and another one for php. Now it is all good for me